# Default Firemonkey style sheet (file) for Delphi XE-6 Firemonkey Desktop Application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Delphi XE-6 Firemonkey

I am trying to custom style the checkbox in a TGrid's TCheckColumn
I want to first understand how the default style is created. What all the elements are that make up its style.

Anyone know how to get the default style sheet for a default Firemonkey desktop application in Delphi XE-6?

If I drop a TGrid on a Firemonkey desktop application, and add a TCheckColumn to the grid, where is this default style of the grid, TCheckColumn / CheckCellStyle coming from?

I am trying to obtain its file (*.style), name. or the text.

If I add a TStyleBook, and then double click it and choose save, it only saves the StyleContainer, none of the styles for any control - especially the grid. Its just empty

```
object TStyleContainer
end
```

I have also tried to see if there was a default name in the StyleManager

```
  for s in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
         ShowMessage(S);
```

Anyone know how to get the default style sheet for a default firemonkey desktop application in Delphi XE-6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the component (eg. Grid) and choose "Edit Style..." or "Edit Default Style" (can't remember which menu was in XE6). This will reveal the style elements of the component. Then you can save them to a .style file.

Comment: Didn't work the first time i tired it. I got an empty TStyleContainer. But i dropped a few more components on form amd tried it again......and BOOM, there it is. Thanks!